# como é que removo este aviso?

Tags: python, flask

Erro:

> C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy__init__.py:839: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
>     'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '

o meu codigo:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///base.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


####################################################################
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
#####################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Adicione a chave de configuração SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS ao app flask.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

Com isso na hora de instanciar o aplicativo na instancia do FlaskSQLAlchemy não será mostrado.

Referências:

[Resposta no Stackoverflow-en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738467/how-do-i-know-if-i-can-disable-sqlalchemy-track-modifications)

[Configurações FlaskSQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/config/)